# Snowflake automatically condenses multiple spaces located consecutively in the middle of a string when displaying results

Tags: sql, user-interface, select, whitespace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

If I run

```
SELECT ('ABC      DEF')
```

I get the following output in the Results pane:

```
'ABC DEF'
```

Note: The spaces are being condensed **only** for the purpose of displaying the record. It keeps all of the spaces but for some reason the browser only shows a single space.

Is there any way to alter the display so that all of the spaces show up? I have columns where records are identical except for the number of consecutive spaces in the middle and they look exactly the same when I select them. Thanks!

**EDIT:** In case it's relevant, I'm viewing the Snowflake UI in Google Chrome.

Comment: It might be Google that is condensing the spaces.

Comment: I fully buy that it's Google doing the condensing. If that is the case, is there a workaround?

Comment: Why not use a different character for spacing?

Comment: Unfortunately I work at a large company and this is a production database. I can't alter the table without fighting an uphill battle against bureaucracy

Comment: @Vincent_Adultman You don't have to alter the table itself. For your purpose, you could just replace those spaces with a different character in your select statement.

Comment: My concern is that other people who use the table and aren't as experienced with SQL won't catch the issue.

Comment: @Vincent_Adultman Snowflake is expected to roll out its desktop application. That's probably your best bet

Comment: @Isildur What desktop application?  There is a new web app available in Preview called Snowsight, and it is better in this case, but it is not a desktop application.

Comment: @MikeWalton Bummer! I thought it would be a desktop app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Snowflake UI is HTML at the end of the day, so HTML naturally condenses spaces.  Not a lot you can do with the current Snowflake UI, but if you switch over to the Preview App (Snowsight) that is current in Public Preview, it handles the display of spaces better.  It isn't the fully functional UI that the Snowflake UI is, but it will continue to get better as Snowflake rolls out new features.